# Laravel on a shared hosting server returns error 500

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using a shared hosting server, I installed my first Laravel 5.4 application and everything is still working fine. A few days ago I installed another Laravel 5.4 application on a different domain, but same server, but when I try to access the URL, I get `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`.

Below is my `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried the following, but same error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ### Add two lines for fix error 500 ###
    Options -Indexes
    php_flag xcache.cacher 0
    #######################################

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You moved everything inside your `public_html` folder which you should not do. Only files inside `/public` needs to be in `public_html`, hence the name `public`. The Laravel files should be placed higher directory where it is not accessible from the public.

1. Install Laravel with Softaculous, or with `composer` via SSH in  `/home/username/laravel`
2. Move everything in `/home/username/public_html` folder to
   `/home/username/laravel`
3. Move everything in `/home/username/laravel/public` to `/home/username/public_html` and delete the public folder after move.
4. Edit this file: `/home/username/public_html/index.php`
5. Change to `require '/home/username/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';`
6. Change to `$app = require_once '/home/username/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';`
7. Save this file and close window.
8. Edit this file: `/home/username/laravel/server.php`
9. Change to:

   ```
   if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists('/home/username/public_html'.$uri)) {
       return false;
   }

   require_once '/home/username/public_html/index.php';
   ```

Replace `username` with your hosting username. :)

Comment: Now it's showing a different error, when I try to access the domain (forumcover.com) it displays the full folder structure of the laravel framework.. When I try to access the login route (forumcover.com/login) I get     NOT FOUND "The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Please remove, you leaked your database details!

Comment: Alright I' will anticipate your response. As for the database details I've changed it.

Comment: Updated the answer, this is as far as I can remember, let me know if it works or I missed some steps. :)

Comment: After following the steps above, I get "The forumcover.com page isn’t working

forumcover.com is currently unable to handle this request."       I moved all files and folders including "cgi-bin"  directory to home/Username/laravel.... Am I supposed to leave the cgi-bin directory in home/username/public_html ?

Comment: Okay updated my answer, I was missing steps, continue with step 8.

Comment: After Continuing  from Step 8, I'm getting same error..." The forumcover.com page isn’t working

forumcover.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Just so you all know, the .htaccess will be vissible to all. change permisons on it.

Comment: Yes it worked , actually it should not be so. All frame work structures should be placed in root (public_HTML) folder.

Comment: No it shouldn't, I've came across these sites and could access their .env file and get database details and other passwords.. was funny :)